# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named with eclipselink

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa

I have a small project running fine in Eclipse. However when I package it in a jar it will fail with No Persistance provider.

I have tried with adding eclipselink as a maven dependency, external jar file and just as a normal project dependency in Eclipse. I have also tried to packaged with extract and package required libraries with no difference.

Worth noting is that the Jersey dependencies will work just fine and call the server with no problem. so those dependencies are working in the .jar file.

```
The Persistence.xml is located in
project/src/META-INF/persistence.xml

I have tried removing one of the persistance-unit without change.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestMDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.sg.db.entity.Result</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:ucanaccess://viking.mdb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="TestMDBLive" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.sg.db.entity.Result</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/Viking2001/DataBas/Viking.mdb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The project is a Maven project. It has external dependencies that I added with

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>ucanaccess</groupId>
 <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
 <scope>system</scope>
 <version>3.0.1</version>
 <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ucanaccess-3.0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>


No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TestMDBLive
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

It will fail at the factory creation in the init()

```
public void init() {

        //Setup database connection
        try {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            em = factory.createEntityManager();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();       }

    }
```

Comment: how do you package your app?

Comment: as a runnable jar in Eclipse

Comment: Try putting `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` in your persistence unit configurations.

Comment: No change doing that. Still same error message. do I need a MANIFEST.MF configured to point to persistence.xml ?

Comment: Where is `persistence.xml` located in the deployed jar file? it should be at `<root>/META-INF/persistence.xml`. If you have put it under `project/src/META-INF` then it's probably misplaced in the resulting jar.

Comment: Copied it to the root with no change in behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally created a normal project that I used configure on and converted it to a maven project.

I re-created the project as a maven project from scratch and copied the resources over. After that the project ran correctly and eclipselink was also included.

To note is that the persistence.xml should still be in src/mail/java/META.INF with no need to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Try packaging your application with [maven assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html).

This will ensure that all dependencies are correctly placed into the jar archive

Comment: Tried it but it will end up not packaging the external jars that are part of the pom.xml

Comment: how do you launch the assembly plugin?

Comment: With mvn package from the prompt no errors in output.

Comment: after configuring the plugin you should run it like this:   mvn clean assembly:single  . More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615634/maven-build-assembly-with-dependencies